# redirect user to login page

Tags: java, javascript, session, jakarta-ee

I'm running a J2EE application and need to redirect the user to login page if the session is inactive.

I basically want to use the below javascript code to get the session last accessed time and compare with the current time, and if its more than the session timeout I will logout:-

```
<script>

        setInterval(function() {

            console.log('MaxInactive Interval ==  ' + <%=new Date(session.getLastAccessedTime())%> );

        }, 10000);
    </script>
```

I get the below error on the console.log line:-

Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Here is the display from the sources tab:-

```
console.log('MaxInactive Interval ==  ' + Sun May 31 20:33:17 EDT 2015 );
```

Comment: Have you tried like this `console.log("MaxInactive Interval == " , <%=new Date(session.getLastAccessedTime())%> );`

Answer (score 0):

You should place the single quote at the end of console.log argument

```
    setInterval(function() {

        console.log('MaxInactive Interval == <%=new Date(session.getLastAccessedTime())%>' );

    }, 10000);
</script>
```

And you don't need the + operator, you cannot concatenate javascript string with java expressions.